# Adding custom elements to aurelia view

Tags: javascript, aurelia, custom-element

Is it possible to load custom elements dynamically?

***Let's say my viewModel looks like this:***

```
export class MyViewModel {
    attached() {
        $(".content").prepend("<card></card>");
        $(".content").prepend("<otherCard></otherCard>");
    }
}
```

Why is aurelia not rendering my "cards". Is there any way i can achive similar behaviour?

Adding those cards directly in `HTML` works great, but i need a more modular approach.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `<compose view-model="card" />` element in the docs. It should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: Totally overlooked this part of the documentation. Thanks!